# Views constrained by width and aspect ratio, not updating height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

So on my main.storyboard, I have an image along with a few buttons. All of them are centered. What I wanted to do was scale everything so that it will look exactly the same from a perspective/ratio point of view, on different devices. That is, if an iPhone 8 Plus is 10 percent bigger than an iPhone 8, I want the buttons and image to be 10 percent bigger on the Plus.

I followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vegamwo6SvU) which told me to constrain the width of the object to a certain percentage of the screen's width (like 25%). Then, he said to constrain the aspect ratio, so that the height will follow along when the width changes based on the screen size.

I did this, for both my buttons and image view. When I look at the dimensions for an object and switch between viewing it through iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone SE, the width changes, but the height does not. So clearly the width is adapting to the screen size properly, but the height isn't. (Note, this is happening for all of the buttons and the image). Should I just constrain the heights and get rid of the aspect ratio constraint? Or is there a way I can fix the aspect ratio so that it does change the height?

Let me know if you have any questions or comments, Looking forward to a response!

EDIT: Per request, here are 2 pictures of the constraints. One is the aspect ratio constraint, the other is the width constraint.

[image: Aspect Ratio Constraints]

[image: Width constraint]

Comment: attach constraints for one item as an example for all

Comment: Did you constrain the button height to its ***own*** width?

Comment: @DonMag No, I didn't constrain the height at all. Just the width with respect to the superview

Comment: My approach would be to (a) remove all constraints on the image, (b) paint it where I want it, (c) **constrain leading and trailing margins** to parent view, (d) constrain aspect ratio, e. center in parent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

[image]

Both buttons have a width constraint of 25% of the view (0.25 * width).

When designing for iPhone SE, they are both `80 x 30`

Button B *also* has an Aspect Ratio constraint of `8:3`

When viewed on an iPhone 8+

[image]

You see that Button A stretches to a width of 103.33, but its height stays at 30.

Button B stretches to a width of 103.33, but because it has a width-to-height ratio constraint, its height *also* stretches. In this case, from 30 to 38.67.

Comment: I believe I have the same thing--I have both the width and aspect ratio constraints. I'm also centering it, but it looks like you do too.

Comment: Take it one step at a time... Add a Top constraint to your image view. Add a width constraint of 0.75 of the view's width. Add an aspect ratio of 31:10. Change the "view as" to different device sizes. Do you get both width and height changing?

Comment: that worked! I ended up just clearing my constraints and trying this, and it worked. I'll upvote your post, but should you create a new 'answer' that I can mark as the solution or should I just mark the solution you already gave as the correct answer?

Comment: I expect it's fine to simply accept it as-is. It was the correct approach, and your comments help clarify.

Comment: great will do! One last question: as I am now attaching the buttons to the image via top constraints, I want to do multipliers to keep it consistent across devices, correct? What is that a multiplier of? The screen height? The image height?

Comment: This is more of a "design" question, but.. If your goal is *proportional spacing* you probably want to look at using `UILayoutGuide` elements: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide

Answer (score 0):

For this work you need

1- width constraint to any percentage of screen

2- aspect ratio constraint

> by ctrl dragging from the element to itself and select aspect ratio from popup then configure the multiplier , e.x 0.5 mean height will be half width

3- origin constraint  x,y

Comment: interesting, why would it need a origin constraint? How would that affect its ability to update the height based on the aspect ratio?

Comment: any item should have x,y constraint to identify it's position , then according to width and height it will stretch , if you want to center items in your case , then you need centerX , with top

Comment: from your screenshoot , red lines means missing constraints , can you specify all constraints you gave , also it's better if you set width  = per*superview.width  , then the other constraint firstItem be height

Comment: @Addison your problem is not in width and aspect ratio constraints , it's in that you don't set top and centerX constraints to the image

Comment: I actually do have a centerX constraint, however that might not have been captured in the screenshot. At any rate, your right, I don't have any top constraint for it. Since the image is toward the top of the screen, and everything else beneath it uses top constraints to attach to it, should I do a "Top Space to Safe Area" constraint? When I try that, all of my other buttons move way too close to the image, so that they overlap. Why would this happen? My constraints between the buttons and image, are all based on multipliers, not constants. Shouldn't they all move up with the image?

Comment: check the constraints between them , percentaging width and height has nothing to do with y constraints , either hook top of image to top safe area , or it's bottom to the item below it that also should be hooked properly , anyway make sure of any item will get it's x,y,width and height constraints , when no red lines then your constraints are ok , otherwise read the red lines error and fix it

Comment: okay, if I am adding x,y, what is the best way to do that so that it will stay consistent ratio-wise? I'm assuming constants would mess it up, since 10 pixels is a larger fraction of the display on an SE than a 8 Plus. Should I use canvas values?

Comment: if you need to maintain aspect ratio to run in all devices , then the problem will be in height or width , and here the scrollview comes in rescue , use standared values as they will change according to device , beside not everything have to be in ib , you have code also to check height and tweak constant and other things if ib will fail to do so